# Recent methods for finding semantic similarity between two short sentences or articles (on a concept level)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk, similarity

I'm working on finding similarities between short sentences and articles. I used many existing methods such as tf-idf, word2vec etc but the results are just okay. The most relevant measure which I found was word moving distance, however, its results are not that better than the other measures. I know it's a challenging problem, however, I am wondering if there are any new methods to find an approximate similarity more on a higher or concept level than just matching words.  Especially, any alternative new methods like word moving distance which looks at slightly higher semantic of a sentence or article?

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't a good fit for SO. If you are asking for guidance to other existing tools, that's considered off-topic. If you want to see people *invent* new methods, you need to get funding for a research project.

Comment: Btw, using word embeddings isn't "just matching words". It should work at a higher semantic level.

Comment: @lenz I didn't mean to find new ways here but to ask if I have missed something which already exists. Maybe something from 2017.

Comment: One expects 'embeddings' to perform well but it doesn't outperform a simple word matching by a big margin, at least in practice.

Answer (score 3):

This is the most recent basing on a paper published 4 months ago.

Step 1:

Load the suitable model using gensim and calculate the word vectors for words in the sentence and store them as a word list

Step 2 : Computing the sentence vector

The calculation of semantic similarity between sentences was difficult before but recently a paper named "[A SIMPLE BUT TOUGH-TO-BEAT BASELINE FOR SENTENCE EMBEDDINGS](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SyK00v5xx)" was proposed which suggests a simple approach by computing the weighted average of word vectors in the sentence and then remove the projections of the average vectors on their first principal component.Here the weight of a word w is a/(a + p(w)) with a being a parameter and p(w) the (estimated) word frequency called smooth inverse frequency.this method performing significantly better.

A simple code to calculate the sentence vector using SIF(smooth inverse frequency) the method proposed in the paper has been given [here](https://github.com/peter3125/sentence2vec)

Step 3: using sklearn cosine_similarity load two vectors for the sentences and compute the similarity.

This is the most simple and efficient method to compute the semantic similarity of sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, this is a huge and busy research area, but I'd say there are two broad types of approaches you could look into:

First, there are some methods that learn sentence embeddings in an unsupervised manner, such as [Le and Mikolov's (2014) Paragraph Vectors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4053v2.pdf), which are implemented in [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html), or [Kiros et al.'s (2015) SkipThought vectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06726), with an [implementation on Github](https://github.com/ryankiros/skip-thoughts).

Then there also exist supervised methods that learn sentence embeddings from labelled data. The most recent one is [Conneau et al.'s (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02364), which trains sentence embeddings on the Stanford Natural Language Inference dataset, and shows these embeddings can be used successfully across a range of NLP tasks. The code is [available on Github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/InferSent).

You might also find some inspiration in [a blog post I wrote earlier this year on the topic of embeddings](http://nlp.yvespeirsman.be/blog/anything2vec/).

Answer (score 1):

To be honest the best thing I know to use for this at the moment is AMR:

- About AMR here: https://amr.isi.edu/
- Documentation here: https://github.com/amrisi/amr-guidelines/blob/master/amr.md

You can use a system like JAMR (see here: https://github.com/jflanigan/jamr) to generate AMRs for your sentence and then you can use Smatch (see here: https://amr.isi.edu/eval/smatch/tutorial.html) to compare the similarity of the two generated AMRs.

What you are trying to do is very difficult and is an active ongoing area of research.

Comment: Is Smatch really a good measure for sentence similarity though? It's (arguably) a good measure for the quality of an AMR *for a given sentence*, but I don't know if it reliably reflects how similar two sentences are. For example, the AMRs for the two sentences "the man ate the cake" and "the boy tasted the pie" would have a *zero* smatch score, but the sentences are pretty similar semantically...

Answer (score 0):

You can use semantic similarity with WordNet for each pair of nouns.
To have a quick look you can enter bird-noun-1 and chair-noun-1 and select wordnet at http://labs.fc.ul.pt/dishin/ it gives you:

Resnik 0.315625756544

Lin 0.0574161071905

Jiang&Conrath 0.0964964414156

The Python code is at: https://github.com/lasigeBioTM/DiShIn